# Big Oh symbol in Taylor expansions

Tags: taylor-expansion

Consider a remainder of some Taylor series: \begin{align}\frac{Mx^6}{C} + \frac{M'x^8}{C'} +  \frac{M'' x^{10}}{C''} + ...\end{align}
I want to replace this with $\mathcal{O}(x^\alpha)$ for the best possible $\alpha$ (in the limit $x \rightarrow 0$). I know the answer is $\alpha = 6$ and it makes intuitive sense, but what is the formal way to prove this?

My attempt is to divide by $x^6$ and show that the expression above approaches the constant $M/C$... and so there definitely exists some other constant $C_0 > M/C$ such the left hand side is less than $C_0$ as long as x is close to 0 .... is this correct? Is it formally correct?

Comment: Don't use series in the first place, instead use the Lagrange error formula. This lets you avoid convergence issues.